# How to install RStudio and R in anaconda

Tags: python, r, anaconda, rstudio, anaconda3

I have been using anaconda environment for python. However, I am not able to install r/rstudio from anaconda.

I opened anaconda and entered commands
**conda install r-essentials** . This ran successfully.

However, **conda install -c r rstudio** is giving me following error:-

````
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: |
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort./
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package vc conflicts for:
rstudio -> vc=14
rstudio -> freetype[version='>=2.9.1'] -> vc[version='10|14|9|9.*|>=14.1,<15.0a0']```
````

Comment: Did you already try to create a new environment for R?

Comment: @JAdel  I directly opened the anaconda prompt and executed conda install r-essentials and conda install -c r rstudio. I did not create any new env for R. R-studios is just an ide for r right? why should I create an env for it? There are preinstalled IDEs but i didnt see any env for it. I am a newbie can you explain it.?

Comment: Its recommended to create a new environment if you use R, see here:   https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/tutorials/create-r-environment/ . In your case it could be possible that your r version conflicts with the anaconda version you are using.

Comment: @JAdel i did not install any R/Python package outside anaconda env. Strange to have this problem

Comment: Rstudio in anaconda channel was not update. This might be the problem because it dont compatible with newer R. I also face this problem and still not found any solution except run R with Jupyter lab.